# How to create semi-transparent content boxes

Tags: css

I would like to make semi-transparent content boxes for my websites pages. My url is: 
http://southcarolinatitleinsurance.com/south-carolina-buyers

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
.entry-content{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

`rgba` is red-green-blue & alpha channel.

Comment: You also want to set a "backup" property like this `.entry-content{background-color:#000;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}`